# How to loop with multiple ResultSet

Tags: java, html, jsp, jdbc, resultset

[image]

I want to replicate what's on the picture shown above 
So I was thinking of using a nested `while` loop using `ResultSet` for each loop accessing different tables in a database as shown on the code below

```
<%
        String Query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction";
        rs = st.executeQuery(Query2);
    %>

    <h2 align="center">Member</h2>
    <%
        while(rs.next())
        {
    %>
            <table bgcolor="#000000" align="center" cellspacing="10px">
                <tr>
                    <th>Transaction ID</th>
                    <th>Transaction Date</th>
                    <th>Costumer Name</th>
                    <th> </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=rs.getString("Transaction_ID")%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString("Transaction_Date")%></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString("User_Name")%></td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    String Query3 = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE User_Name = '"+rs.getString("User_Name")+"' AND Date = '"+rs.getString("Transaction_Date")+"'";
                    ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery(Query3);

                    while(rs2.next())
                    {
                %>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Product</td>
                            <td>Quantity</td>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Total</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="Picture/<%=rs.getString("Image")%>"></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString("Quantity")%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString("Price")%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString("Total")%></td>
                        </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>
            <br/>
    <%
        }
    %>
```

But I got an error saying `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`

 So I tried using another variable for the `ResultSet` which is `rs2` but I still receive the same error message

 How do I fix this? Or is there any other method that I could use to do this?

The 2 tables that I use here has the same value on field User_Name and Transaction_Date as shown on `Query3`

Comment: You can create a single query to select the value from both tables and you will have only one `ResultSet` object to loop through. You should look into the SQL `JOIN` clause.

Comment: I think this query should do it `SELECT transaction.*, list.* FROM transaction LEFT JOIN list ON transaction.User_Name = list.User_Name;`

Comment: My suggestion would be performing the database connection in individual java classes not in on jsp. Also go through servlet in between. Then it should be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see you are using same Statement object for both queries. As documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says, By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.